# How to use the Mockito.verify() as an if condition

Tags: mockito

I know the regular function of Mockito.verify(), but I am wondering how to make it as an if condition like this:

```
if(verify(mocked, times(1)).method()){
     //Do something when the method was called for the first time
}else if(verify(mocked, times(2)).method()){
     //DO something else when the method was caled for the second time
};
```

Comment: “_Do something when_” - this is stubbing not verification.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for your idea! I found the solution then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785498/simulate-first-call-fails-second-call-succeeds