# Writing Unit Test for Failsafe Retry and Timeout policy

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-failsafe

Using Failsafe by jhalterman for the first time ( [GIT](https://github.com/failsafe-lib/failsafe), [Website](https://failsafe.dev/) ) to add a simple asynchronous module to send sms. I am using only Retry and Timeout policy and implementation is working fine

```
Failsafe.with(timeoutPolicy, retryPolicy)
    .with(getExecutorService())
    .runAsync(() -> sendSMS(msg, mobile));
```

Now I am struggling to write a unit test case for this.

How can I mock a failure to retry or timeout to write tests like `sendSmsOneRetry`, `sendSmsTwoRetry` or `sendSmsTimeout`?

I have Mockito available too in project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785498/simulate-first-call-fails-second-call-succeeds